# How to run Ansible task to a limit number of items?

Tags: ansible

I have a dynamic inventory which returns me my hosts addresses.

But sometimes, I would like to apply some configuration to a limited number of hosts.

A sample with N hosts but only 5 are echoed:

```
- name: "Run silly shell script"
  shell: |
    echo {{ item }}
    exit 0
  with_items: "{{ hosts | only(5) }}"
```

Comment: what do you mean `limited`? what is the criteria to select the X hosts out of the Z you have?

Comment: I have a list with 10 elements and I would like to get only 5 of them [0..4] (considering the example).

Comment: the first 5 of them ? ok, please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

to get the first X elements from a list, use: `list_var[:X]`.

full example as PB below:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    list_var:
    - 1
    - 2
    - 3
    - 4
    - 5
    - 6


  tasks:


  - name: print full list
    debug:
      var: list_var

  - name: print list of first 3 elements
    debug:
      var: list_var[:3]
```

hope it helps.